# Censoring for events that don't occur

Tags: cox-model, censoring

I have data on when the time between two events A and B. However, I am assuming if the time between them is more than 5 hours then the two events are unrelated and so we assume that on these occasions B does not occur.  I've been told to run a proportional hazards model on the data set and censor for times greater than 5 hours. However, censoring appears to be for unknown lengths of time which doesn't seem to fit here.

Is there a standard way to approach this?

Comment: *Censoring* can also be thought of as the *absence* of a terminal event, e.g., failure, death or "B" (in your case), within a span of time. The "unknown" part has less to do with indeterminate time than it does with an indeterminate terminating event.

Comment: Thanks very much.   That clears it up a lot.  I looked in quite a few places but it all referred to unknown times rather than absent events. :)